# exchangeable implementations of (google/openlayers)maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, openlayers, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write a JavaScript to read information out of a table and put markers on a map, depending on the data(Coordinates are hidden in that table).
For each row there will be a marker on the map.

I have written the Script with google-maps-apiv3, but I want to be independent of google and want to be able to switch to OpenLayers. I didn't invest much time in OpenLayers, but the markers I have seen in some examples, are plain ugly :S. On the other hand google-maps has restrictions and boundaries for free usage.

How would you write your JavaScript to be able to replace the implementations? I want to seperate my businesslogic(table to map+markers) out, decouple it from the map implementation.
On what file and how do I bind/import the implementation? How to keep the JavaScript testable (I use Jasmine+Testacular)? I would use mocking if possible.

FYI: I am a Java guy, maybe my OO mind can't see the solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about an [abstraction layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer).  What you'll need to do is determine the functionality you'll need for your maps:

- Markers
- Info Window
- Map

Any additional functionality that you know you'll need should be added to the list.  Then, for each item, you'll create an abstract representation, following the [Bridge Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).  For example, you'll have an abstract `map` class that will encapsulate a `google.maps.Map` and/or an `OpenLayers.Map`.

```
function MartinL.Map()
{
    var map;
    if(google && google.maps) //google maps api has been loaded
        map = new google.maps.Map();
    else
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
}

var myMap = new MartinL.Map();
```

This is obviously far too simple of an example, but what you'd do is wrap the google maps and OpenLayer maps implementations in your abstraction layer.  Refactor your existing code to use only your abstraction layer, and then you can switch libraries whenever you please.